# path_provider getExternalStorageDirectories() returns only one directory

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins

I expected it to return a list of the various directories in the device's internal storage. Instead it returns the path to the app directory itself. I tried using `for` loops and `forEach` but both return only one directory.

```
void getFiles() async {
    var directories = await getExternalStorageDirectories();
    directories!.toList();
    for (var i = 0; i < directories.length; i++) {
      print(directories);
    }

    directories.forEach((element) {
      print(element);
    });
  }
```

I've also tried the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < directories.length; i++) {
      print(directories[i].path);
}
```

```
for (var i = 0; i < directories.length; i++) {
      print(directories[i]);
}
```

All four return the same directory:

```
'/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.app/files'
```

How can I list all of the directories?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get subdirectories of a directory do that:

```
List sublist = await Directory(directories[i].path).list().map((event) => event.path).toList();
      for (var j = 0; j < sublist.length; j++) {
        print(sublist[j]);
      }
```